# Nuclide packages on windows 7

Tags: windows, nuclide-editor

I installed  Atom and then from it's package manager I installed the "nuclide-installer" package which is expected to install all the nuliclide packages. After Atom's restart I can see just the nuclide-language-hack package. Any suggestion on how to get all the needed packages?

Comment: This might be the same issue: https://github.com/facebook/nuclide/issues/118

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2016/01/13, Nuclide is a single Atom package named ['nuclide'](https://atom.io/packages/nuclide). The 'nuclide-installer' package is no longer needed or supported. Once `apm install nuclide` completes, you are good to go.

There is more info in the Nuclide v0.111.0 blog post: http://nuclide.io/blog/2016/01/13/Nuclide-v0.111.0-The-Unified-Package/